# "Equity" system in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I have this game where I am creating a dummy "equity" system, say player A pays 50$ for a property which is worth 20$ (buys 100%), then player B comes along and pays 10$ (now putting player A at 83.3333% and player B at 16.6666%) how can I calculate how much player A made (since he got 100% up until player B bought a share and 83.3333% since then).

I have a "bought" MySql database schema along with date columns, property value at time of purchase and of course the $ that the player has paid, just thinking of how to write queries to get the values makes my brain hurt so I would appreciate any pointers.

What makes everything very tricky is that every player can then purchase another share of the property, making the process even more difficult.

Comment: Can you provide the code you have and expected and actual results? or can you make an SQLfiddle example

Comment: Didn't know SQLfiddle existed lol, the code is a series of queries that are relatively straightforward as well as the question, in my case if the property value grows by another 20$ then player A has $33.3 worth of house and player B has 6.6$ worth of house which is invalid. Player A needs to have 36.6 and player B needs to have 3.3. My first instinct is to fetch all the data and loop through it but then it won't work with more than 2 players and/or the same player buying twice.

Comment: So all that you need is a pure database implementation of a system that calcualates the present percentage holding of each participant?

Comment: Will that even work? I guess you could say that in the end Player A had 91.5% and Player B had 8.5%

Comment: Anyone? I still can't get it

Comment: It's not at all clear what output you want returned from the query. So the "percentages" change with purchase dates, giving percentages as of an effective date. But what do you mean by "how much player A made"? Is there a sale involved as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a trigger, in case if you want this done automatically, however for the moment I will concentrate on the actual query. So let us say you have two fields, one saying value held and other saying percentage held (other fields, as per business need can exist), but let me show you an example using only these two fields

```
Person | Value | Percentage
```

Let us further assume, as per your example that A buys $50 worth of shares

You need to call (after insert trigger may be fine, or called separately) this query which uses a not-so-recommended approach to updating table based on its own aggregate values by using a second sub-query. However if you want to do it clean then you need to update two tables, one which will hold the values of shares and second which will hold the percentages.

```
CREATE TABLE SHARES (NAME VARCHAR(20), VALUE INTEGER, PERCENTAGE FLOAT);

INSERT INTO SHARES (NAME,VALUE) VALUES ('A',50);

UPDATE SHARES SET PERCENTAGE = VALUE/(SELECT TOTAL_VALUE FROM
                                      (SELECT SUM(VALUE) AS TOTAL_VALUE
                                       FROM SHARES) AS DUMMY)*100;

INSERT INTO SHARES (NAME,VALUE) VALUES ('B',10);

UPDATE SHARES SET PERCENTAGE = VALUE/(SELECT TOTAL_VALUE FROM
                                      (SELECT SUM(VALUE) AS TOTAL_VALUE
                                       FROM SHARES) AS DUMMY)*100;
```

Fiddle found at http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cec38/1/0  Hope this helps.